# Can I make Shutter use standard notifications?

Tags: notification, notify-osd, shutter

When taking a screenshot with a delay, [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) shows the countdown to when the screenshot will be taken, using its own custom notifications *(see screenshot)*. Is there anyway to make Shutter use the standard notifications?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up the Preferences window (Edit -> Preferences or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ) and click on the *Behavior* tab, change the *Notification agent* combobox from *Built-in* to *Desktop Notifications*.

[image]

Shutter will now use the standard *(In this case Notify OSD)* notifications:

[image]